# order (picking list) pdf, sort by location code

Tags: magento-1.8, pdf

We have made a PDF picking list, which also shows the location codes of the products. 
The attribute for the location code is:

```
$Location = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProductId())->getData('location_shelf');
```

I am trying to sort the list by location code

So far I only found a piece of code which sorts the products by name

```
$items = $order->getAllItems()  ; // Gets items --- need to sort them first! 
        $_sortedItems = array();        
            // build array, inserts order items into array and sort

        foreach ($items as $item) :
            $_sortedItems[$item->getName()] = $item;
        endforeach;

        ksort($_sortedItems);
        foreach ($_sortedItems as $item) {   //pass sorted items back one at a time in alpha' order

        if ($item->getParentItem()) {
            continue;

            }
```

When I change the `item->getName` into

```
$item->getData('location_shelf')
```

It just shows 1 product on the picking list.

How do I correctly adjust it so my picking lists sorts by `location_shelf`?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer:

in /app/code/local/Your/Extension/etc/config.xml
add

```
<global>
<sales>
    <quote>
        <item>
            <product_attributes>
                <location_shelf />
            </product_attributes>
        </item>
    </quote>
</sales>
```

and here is the piece of code I used in /app/code/local/Your/Extension/Model/Order/Pdf/Order.php

```
  /* Add body */
       $items = $order->getAllItems()  ; // Gets items --- need to sort them first! 
        $_sortedItems = array();        
            // build array, inserts order items into array and sort

        foreach ($items as $item) :
            $_sortedItems[$item->getProduct()->getData("location_shelf")] = $item;
        endforeach;

        ksort($_sortedItems);
        foreach ($_sortedItems as $item) {   //pass sorted items back one at a time in alpha' order

        if ($item->getParentItem()) {
            continue;

            }

            if ($this->y < 200) {
                $page = $this->newPage(array());
            }

            $position++;
            /* Draw item */
```

I used

```
  $_sortedItems[$item->getProduct()->getData("location_shelf")] = $item;
```

instead of

```
 $item->getName
```

It's inside

```
 public function getPdf($orders = array())
```

Comment: This only prints the line when there is a unique location_shelf, how to print all products even if the location_shelf is the same?